# SuppressOutput() doesn't work in combination with other WithoutEndTag TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I started with the `ConditionTagHelper` from the Microsoft documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring#condition-tag-helper
and added my own

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = nameof(Disabled), TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class DisabledTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (Disabled) output.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Now, `<input>` will be supressed

```html
<input disabled="true" condition="false" value="disabled && suppressed">
```

and `<fieldset></fieldset>` will  be suppressed, but its content won't

```html
<fieldset disabled="true" condition="false"><input value="disabled && suppressed"></fieldset>
```

What do I wrong?

---

Not the best Workaround:

- Remove all `TagStructure.WithoutEndTag` from `TagHelper` implementations.
- Add self-closing end tags `/>` to all tags without a closing tag (otherwise: *Found a malformed 'input' tag helper. Tag helpers must have a start and end tag or be self closing.*)

(I don't like this workaround because adding/removing `TagStructure` of a `TagHelper` forces me to add/remove self-closing end tags.)